# How to input certain puzzles from a collection?

Tags: input, exercisebank

I'm building a database of math puzzles that each TEX file gathers puzzles in one year such as 2017.tex may have 10 of them, each puzzle and its solution with a label.

Now I give talks and want to choose problems and solutions from these files now and then. Should I use `\input` and `\chapter` commands? I'm not using all the puzzles in one file and I don't want to write each puzzle as one TEX file. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I made a package just for purposes like this. It's called [`exercisebank`](https://ctan.org/pkg/exercisebank).

Say you have your `2017.tex`, and in there you should have puzzles and solutions in the following format.

```
%% 2017.tex
%% Heads up! \end{solution} and \end{problem} can't have spaces in front of it and needs it's own line
\begin{problem}
  Puzzle 1 here
\end{problem}
\begin{solution}
  Solution 1 here
\end{solution}

\begin{problem}
  Puzzle 2 here
\end{problem}
\begin{solution}
  Solution 2 here
\end{solution}
```

Now you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exercisebank}
% You might want no part problem headers (only Problem 1, Problem 2 etc), in that case: uncomment the line below:
% \exercisebanksetup{part problems=Off}
% To make a setup, you do this; \makeset{setupName}{puzzle-file}
% So to make a setup with all of the exercises from 2017:
\makeset{allof2017}{2017}
% Or you can cherry pick your favorites
\makeset{2017Favorites}{\select{2017}{1,2}}
\begin{document}
  % Then choose which to build
  \buildset{2017Favorites}
\end{document}
```

---

If you end up using this, please feel free to request features or report bugs [here](https://github.com/Strauman/exerciseBank/issues)

---

Edit: I've now come across some other packages that do similar things. So I should also mention that e.g. [`xsim`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xsim) might also do what you want, and is probably more stable at this time. Furthermore, you could check out the  [`exercise`](https://ctan.org/topic/exercise) and [`exam`](https://ctan.org/topic/exam) topics on CTAN.

Comment: I made 3 TEX files and 2 of them have 2 puzzles each. When I make a setup using all the problems, it shows Problem 1 b), 2b) 2c) and 3b) 3c). Why? I am supposed that it shows Problem 1-5. Thanks!

Comment: This functionality is on the todo list and will be added in the next version. Probably some time this week or beginning of next week :) I’ll let you know!

Comment: Sure, I will expand my database first and wait for your next version. Thank you!

Comment: I have pushed an update to CTAN. It'll probably be available on CTAN some time tomorrow, but TeXLive and MiKTeX might take a few more days. To convert part problems into normal problems you could just do `\exercisebanksetup{part problems=Off}`

Comment: How is it working for you, @HaoranChen

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I will next time, in a few weeks.