# Slow typesetting due to xsim package - Any way to speed it up?

Tags: xsim

I really appreciate the `xsim` package and it's functionality. However, when including many questions, the typesetting slows down considerably (in my setup, up to 10 minutes for around 200 included questions).

Is there any known way to speed up the typesetting using `xsim` **without** resorting to alternatives as discussed in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/435390/xsim-slow-with-external-files)?

Thanks in advance and best regards, Manuel

Comment: Have you tried measuring what's the bottleneck? Quite probably it's disk I/O, so nothing which could be improved.

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks! After your comment, I tried to find the bottleneck. However, it's hard for me to evaluate where the problem lies: The disk does not seem to be tasked that much (around 1 MB write and 20 MB read in 5 min), but the CPU seems to be at 100 % capacity. Is this enough to make the disk I/O the bottleneck?

Comment: Don't forget that TeX is single-threaded, so it should max out one core. Concerning disk I/O it's only a suspicion as xsim writes every exercise to a temporary file and reads it in when typesetting.

Comment: @TeXnician Makes sense. Thanks again for your input.